# Rooted or not, I can not figure out

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, root-access, imei

I don't know if someone already rooted my Samsung Sm-t530.
Can somebody help me?

I just find some files like

```
Knox emulated
Emulated
Extsdcard
Sdcard
Mnt
Storage/emulated
Dev/emulated
```

And i cannot find Imei.

Comment: Install `ES file explorer` from play store, and open app and tap on settings ( top-left), going down you can see 'Root Explorer', activate it, if rooted it shows which type permission required('R'-Read only, 'R/W'-'Read/Write), else not rooted(shows, test failed)

Comment: Also, if just tap on internal memory , tap on `storage`, then `/` symbol. if it displays file contents, device ROOTED.

Answer (score 1):

Download a root check app or look at your settings and see if you have anything like supersu installed. There is many root check apps on the play store which you can use. You can check your imei number in the phone near the battery (or under the battery if it's a removal battery).

Answer (score 1):

- either you use a app to check if you gained root:
  i would advise [Root Verifier](https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdid=com.abcdjdj.rootverifier), it is free (as in beer and speech), ad-free, uses no further permissions and also checks for `busybox` and a superuser-app.
- or on the other side, you can simply check it by terminal with the `su`-command:
  but i would only recommend this method if there is a terminal-emulator already installed, you need just a quick check once and you know what are you doing with a terminal...!

---

if you need additional identifiers (like the IMEI) i can advise [Get ID](https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdid=makeinfo.com.getid); it displays

- Device ID
- SIM serial number
- WiFi mac address
- IMEI
- IMSI
- Google Service key

and in the help-menu a little explanation for every entry can be shown.

Answer (score 1):

Download Root Verifier app from google play store and it will tell you whether or not your device is rooted or not?